# how to download a file using python-sharepoint library

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using this library https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint to connect to a SharePoint list. I can authenticate, access the list fields, including the full URL to the file I want, and it seems this library does have `is_file()` and `open()` methods however, I do not understand how to call these.
Any advice is appreciated!

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener 

opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "domain/username", "password")
site = SharePointSite(server_url, opener)

sp_list = site.lists['ListName']
for row in sp_list.rows:
       print row.id, row.Title, row.Author['name'], row.Created, row.EncodedAbsUrl
       #download file
       #row.open() ??
```

To quote from ReadMe file:

> Support for document libraries is limited, but SharePointListRow
>   objects do support a is_file() method and an open() method for
>   accessing file data.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you call these methods on the list row (which is of type `SharePointListRow`).
The `open()` method is actually the method of **urllib2**'s opener, which you usually use like so:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
response = opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
print ('READ CONTENTS:', response.read())
print ('URL          :', response.geturl())
# ....
```

So you should be able to use it like this (I don't have any Sharepoint site to check this though):

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener 

opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "domain/username", "password")
site = SharePointSite(server_url, opener)

sp_list = site.lists['ListName']
for row in sp_list.rows():                # <<<
   print row.id, row.Title, row.Author['name'], row.Created, row.EncodedAbsUrl
   # download file here 

   print ( "This row: ", row.name() )     # <<<
   if row.is_file():                      # <<<
      response = row.open()               # <<<
      file_data = response.read()         # <<<

      # process the file data, e.g. write to disk
```